# How do I traverse the attributes to build a decision tree using ID3?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am just starting to learn python but I have a task that requires me to build a decision tree from scratch using the ID3 algorithm. I have been looking for some examples online. I understand the inner workings of the algorithm but I am struggling to translate it into code. I would appreciate some help to understand what is going on in the code snippets below. Assuming that the entropy and information gain function is done, these functions are needed to build the tree.

I am getting an error with the has_key part since i am using python 3.6

for record in data:
        if (val_freq.has_key(record[target_attr])):
            val_freq[record[target_attr]] += 1.0
        else:
            val_freq[record[target_attr]] = 1.0

Comment: You should cook your question down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: maybe i will first start to find out how to solve the error with this piece of code below. how do I change the has_key as I am using python 3.6 now    for record in data:
        if (val_freq.has_key(record[target_attr])):
            val_freq[record[target_attr]] += 1.0
        else:
            val_freq[record[target_attr]] = 1.0